# PHP Menu with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match

First sorry for my bad English.

I have this menubar in PHP. I want that if an user is on a page the current menuitem gets another color. I had a code that works, but if i have a page like /item.php?id=9 , it wont work. So i tried this with preg_match, but i can't get it to work.

Menu :

```
<li <?php unset($pageURL); getSelected("/index.php") ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li <?php unset($pageURL); getSelected("/item.php") ?>><a href="item.php">Item</a></li>
<li <?php unset($pageURL); getSelected("/more.php") ?>><a href="more.php">More</a></li>
```

Function getSelected:

```
Function getSelected($nameURL){
$curURL =$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$pattern = "~$nameURL/.*~";
    if(preg_match($pattern, $curURL)){
        echo 'class="selected"';
        unset($curURL);
    }
    unset($curURL);
}
```

How can i fix this with preg_match?

Thank you!

Comment: Just some coding advice: No need to unset your function variable since php will handle that automatically. It just increases maintenance costs. Also the function name is misleading since you don't get anything you just print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) in combination with [`parse_url()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) would do the job. It returns the filename of an URL:

```
function getSelected($nameURL){
    $currentfile = basename(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH));
    if($currentfile === $nameURL){
        echo 'class="selected"';
    }
}
```

And in HTML e.g.:

```
<li <?php getSelected("item.php") ?>><a href="item.php">Item</a></li>
```

No need for RegEx here.

Answer (score 0):

It is faster (CPU cycles) and easier (coding) in this situation to just use a php string function.

```
if (stripos($curURL, $pattern) !== false) {
  echo 'class="selected"'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be the trailing `/` in `$pattern`. Try replacing

```
$pattern = "~$nameURL/.*~";
```

with

```
$pattern = "~$nameURL/?.*~";
```

Also, I'm not sure, but you'd better escape the `.` in your `getSelected` calls, because with your pattern `/itemdphp` will match too.

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no reason to unset a variable so many times. Just do it once at the beginning:

```
<?php unset($pageURL);?>
<li <?php getSelected("/index.php") ?>><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li <?php getSelected("/item.php") ?>><a href="item.php">Item</a></li>
<li <?php getSelected("/more.php") ?>><a href="more.php">More</a></li>
```

Then try the following regex in your function:

`$pattern = "/\/$nameURL(.*)/";`

`getSelected('item.php')` will match, for example, `/item.php` or `/item.php?something=stuff&othervar=lollipop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
$pattern = $nameURL . '$/';
preg_match($pattern, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

Because you already have a `/` in the front .